# Laravel: ErrorException Undefined variable: items

Tags: laravel

So i want to be able to view my cart on one of my pages. I can simply 'add to cart' and the value of the number of items in my cart will show on the top right corner of my page. When i go to click on the cart i receive this error:

ErrorException
Undefined variable: items.
I have the following code:

Cart.php:

```
   class Cart {

public $items = null;
public $totalQty = 0;
public $totalPrice = 0;

public function __Construct($oldCart)
{
    if ($oldCart) {
        $this->$items = $oldCart->$items;
        $this->$totalQty = $oldCart->$totalQty;
        $this->$totalPrice = $oldCart->$totalPrice;
    }

}
public function add($item, $id){
    $storedItem = ['qty' => 0, 'price' => $item->price, 'item' => $item];
    if($this->items) {
        if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
            $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
    }
    $storedItem['qty'] ++;
    $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
    $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
    $this->totalQty++;
    $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
}
```

PostsController.php:

```
public function getCart() {
if (!Session::has('cart')) {
    return view('posts.shopping-cart', ['post' => null]);
}
$oldCart = Session::get('cart');
$cart = new Cart($oldCart);
return view('posts.shopping-cart', ['post' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice'=> $cart->totalPrice]);
  }
```

Payment.blade:

```
@if(Session::has('cart'))
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-0ffset-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach($posts as $post)
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <span class="badge">{{ $post['qty']}}</span>
                    <strong>{{ $post['item']['title']}}</strong>
                        <span class="label label-success">{{$post['price']}}</span>
                <div class="btn-group">
```

Web.api

```
Route::get('/shopping-cart', [ 'uses' => 'PostsController@getCart', 'as' => 'product.shoppingCart' ]);
```

But when i click on the my cart link that is in navbar.php:

```
   <a class="nav-link " href="{{ route('product.shoppingCart')}}">Cart 
   Cart {{ Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : ''}}
```

I then get the error undefined items variable

Comment: kindly show what you have in cart i.e when they are saved in the session or show the code where you put the cart into the session

Comment: so when when i do dd it will show that the post has gone into the cart. I can also book multiple rooms which add to my cart. For some reason when i click on my cart, i get the errror undefined variables

Comment: Where did you put the cart value to the session? Show that code.

Comment: See edited code, i have added navbar.php which is the section where i press the cart and its route is to 'product.shoppingCart'

Comment: Please dump the entire stack trace... Look in `storage/logs/laravel.log` -- and the trace beginning with the error you describe (not the contents of the entire file)

Comment: [2020-04-09 18:48:48] local.ERROR: Undefined variable: items {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: items at C:\\Users\\karan\\Documents\\xamppfyp\\htdocs\\FYP\\app\\Cart.php:16)
[stacktrace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on the constructor of the `Cart` class. You have put the dollar sign on the property names.

Just remove the dollar signs.

```php
public function __Construct($oldCart)
{
    if ($oldCart) {
        $this->items = $oldCart->items;
        $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
        $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
    }

}
```